# Convergence of series of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Random variables $X_1,X_2,...,\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,...$ are independent, $X_n$ has exponential distribution with parameter $n$ and $\varepsilon$ has distribution $P(\varepsilon_n=1)=P(\varepsilon_n=-1)=1/2$.
For what values of $\alpha\geq0$ the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\varepsilon_nX_n^\alpha$$ is convergent almost surely? How do I approach this question?

Comment: what's exponential distribution?

Comment: you could show $E|\sum_n \epsilon_n X_n^\alpha|^2 < \infty$

Comment: Try with Kolmogorov's three-series theorem or Kolmogorov's two-series theorem